# Flutter / Release mode in IOS device is not working properly

Tags: flutter

I am developing mobile app with flutter.

Onew I flutter run --release on my physical iOS device, it installed but once I press app,
it just show me splash screen and terminated. It was working fine before and also it is working
fine in debug mode.

Can I know reason why this happen ?

Thanks for reading.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on macOS 11.0.1 20B50 darwin-x64, locale en-CA)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be cause of datetime format not support locale if your app using localization.It occur only release mode.